# Apache Flink: Google Cloud PubSub Connector: Unable to set attributes to the Pubsub Messages

Tags: java, apache-flink, google-cloud-pubsub

Here I need to set some attributes to the Pubsub Messages before publishing them to the Google PubSub.
For example:

```
{
  "data": "Pubsub message data...",
  "attributes": {
    "attribute1": "value 1",
    "attribute2": "value 2",
  }
}
```

However, I did not find a way to achieve this with Apache Flink Google Cloud PubSub connector for Java([here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/pubsub/#google-cloud-pubsub)). The message publishing part of the library looks like below, where it only sets the data to the Pubsub message while not setting the attributes.

```
 @Override
    public void invoke(IN message, SinkFunction.Context context) {
        PubsubMessage pubsubMessage =
                PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                        .setData(ByteString.copyFrom(serializationSchema.serialize(message)))
                        .build();

        ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
        numPendingFutures.incrementAndGet();
        ApiFutures.addCallback(future, failureHandler, directExecutor());
    }
```

I am new to Apache Flink. Much appreciate any help on this to find out a way to set the attributes to the Pubsub messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Came here searching for a solution, looks like we need to submit a patch :)